How to stop jQuery from formatting sub table
I am creating a table using jQuery, doing something like this:
var table = $('#table_id');
var row;

for (i in data) { // pseudocode
    row = $('<tr>');

    // add some regular cells
    row.append( $("<td>").text(other_data) );

    // add a sub table
    row.append( $("<td>").html(sub_table) );

    // add row to table
    table.append(row);
}

$('#table_id tr:odd').addClass("some_color_class");

My issue is that jQuery is counting the rows in the sub table when doing the coloring... if the sub table has an odd number of rows, then two adjacent rows will be the same color:

How can I have jQuery only look at $('#table_id tr:odd') elements where tr:odd is an immediate child of table_id?

Try using the child combinator.

@mykaf, thanks! That's what I needed! I'd be happy to accept your answer if you want to post one.
